# Avoiding currency exchange fees on credit card security deposits

Tags: credit-card, foreign-exchange, fees, refund

I recently did a warranty exchange with a $25 service fee:

- I gave $500 deposit on my VISA card.
- They shipped the replacement.
- I returned the old item.
- They refunded $475 to my VISA card.

which from my point of view means I paid $25.

The complicating factor was that the warranty was with a US company and I was in Canada.

I expected to pay $25 plus the standard 2½% exchange fee, or $25.63. And that *is* what happened, but I also paid a 2½% fee on the $500 deposit *and* on the $475 refund.

The result is that instead of the expected 63 cents, I ended up paying $25 in exchange fees on what was effectively a $25 transaction.

Even so, what the company and VISA each did was both obvious and reasonable, so I can't blame either of them.
It was my mistake for not thinking about it first.

The company didn't offer any option other than credit card for the deposit.

The question is, **what could I have done differently to avoid this reasonable but exorbitant fee?**

*Note that the above amounts are all in US$, and the situation is independent of what the actual exchange rate was.  To make it easy assume the rate was 1:1.*

Comment: This does not seem reasonable. They could have authorized the credit card for $500 and only settled it if you didn't return the item. The authorization would not have cost you anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your simplest path is to find a bank/credit card that doesn't charge you foreign transaction fees. We have these in the US although I assume banks make up for it with a worse exchange rate, so you might end up paying this anyways. I don't know about Canada.

Comment: Yes, we did eventually get a no-fee US$ credit card and bank account, which will also be handy when traveling in the US (which of course we haven't done because COVID-19 happened right after we got it).